# Inconsistency using map in python

Tags: python

I have a constants file `constants.py` like so:

```
querystring = {
    "limit":"10000",
    "sort":"desc"
}

dummy1 = {
    "a": "22",
    "q": "*",
}

dummy2 = {
    "a": "24",
    "q": "**",
}

streams = [dummy1, dummy2]
```

I'm trying to initialise a list by manipulating the values from the `constants.py` file.

```
from constants import querystring, streams
def setParams(dummy, querystring):
    ld = {}
    ld["query"] = setQuerystring( dummy, querystring)
    print ld
    return ld

def setQuerystring( dummy, querystring):
    query = querystring
    query["filter"] = "stream:" + dummy["a"]
    query["query"] = dummy["q"]
    return query

l = map(lambda x: setParams(x, querystring), streams)
print l[0]
print l[1]
```

While the lambda function is running, the output is correctly printed, but when I see the final value returned by the map, the values are different. Why this inconsistency?

The program output:

```
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:22', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '*'}} # l[0] -> during lambda execution
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:24', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '**'}} # l[1] -> during lambda execution
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:24', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '**'}} # l[0] -> from map 
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:24', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '**'}} # l[1] -> from map
```

Comment: `querystring` is in fact mutable `dict`. `query = querystring` does not create a copy of dict, but uses reference instead. In `setQuerystring` you modify same dict instance over and over again. Try `query = querystring.copy()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing and modifying the `querystring` dict across iterations. Later changes from successive iterations are therefore propagated to previously attached copies. You should consider attaching a copy to each dict instead, and modifying that copy:

```
def setQuerystring( dummy, querystring):
    query = querystring.copy()
    ...
```

---

```
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:22', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '*'}}
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:24', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '**'}}
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:22', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '*'}}
{'query': {'sort': 'desc', 'filter': 'stream:24', 'limit': '10000', 'query': '**'}}
```

Comment: I was under the assumption that the default behaviour was to copy, not change the existing object.